# When is Mooncrash progress erased?

Tags: prey

I have read in a few guides that "finishing" Mooncrash erases all your progress. However, it is never clearly explained what exactly constitutes finishing it. Is it one of these, or a combination?

- Completing all Story Objectives
- Completing all KASMA Orders
- Escaping with all five characters in a single run

I don't want to accidentally finish the game and miss out on some achievements such as Cryptomancer or Galaxy Brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you complete the final KASMA Order then you get another call from Basilisk and can no longer enter the simulation.

If you missed some achievements you'll have to start a new game at that point.

Note that the five-escape run and all story objectives are KASMA Orders themselves. It's likely that one of these will be the final order you complete.